# traincascade to train detector of moles in faces

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using createsamples.exe and traincascade.exe to train a detector for moles in faces.

I use 150 positive images (images of faces), where each image contains several moles, in total (all the 150 images) contain 1452 moles; this information is saved in the positive.txt file, propierly. I also use 1015 negative images of skin zones without moles, and this information is propierly saved in the negative.txt file.

To create the positive samples I executed the following command line:

`createsamples.exe -info positive.txt -vec positive.vec -w 3 -h 7`

that successfully creates a positive vector of 1000 samples; I use w = 3 and h = 7 because the moles marked in the positive images and the zones of skin in the negative images are really small.

Then, after execute this command line for finally train the detector:

`traincascade.exe -data result\ -vec positive.vec -bg negative.txt -numStages 20 -nsplits 1 -minhitrate 0.998 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -numPos 150 -numNeg 1015 -w 3 -h 7`

I obtained this:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: result\
vecFileName: positive.vec
bgFileName: negative.txt
numPos: 150
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 3
sampleHeight: 7
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   150 : 150
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.
```

I don't know what happens. Please help me...

Comment: it says the training parameters are problematic. check the docs of opencv, probably the size of the classifier is the problem or number (or format) of samples

Comment: @Nikos M. the problem is that I don't find much documentation about traincascade. I have been following some examples in the web that work fine, so... I don't know where is the error...

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?  Better yet, why is it on StackOverflow?  Typing in a command line is not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  It's about running a program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the -numPos parameter. The -numPos parameter should be less than the total number of positives in your .vec file. Try setting it to 130.

You might want to consider your -numStages parameter as well. You will be overtraining your classifier since you only have 150 positives. Check this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/7141/about-traincascade-paremeters-samples-and-other/) for more details on traincascade paramaters.

Also by running the command   "createsamples.exe -info positive.txt -vec positive.vec -w 3 -h 7" you would get a vector of 150 samples not 1000.

Comment: It could  be a problem with your negative.txt. Are you sure you have the path to your negative samples correctly specified in negatives.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `negative.txt` is ill-formed, because `traincascade.exe` outputs the consumed positives but the negatives does not. The paths of negative examples should be relative to the `traincascade.exe`'s directory.

Comment: I have a haar folder that contains: createsamples.exe, traincascade.exe, Negative and Positive folders with the corresponding images inside it, positive.txt (with something like this for each line: Positive/img1.jpg 2 132 143 10 20 201 300 6 11) negative.txt (with something like this for each line: Negative/nimg1.jpg), an empty result folder for the cascade.xml and the positive.vec resulting of running cretesamples.exe. I execute the command lines from the haar folder...I don't think is a path problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you previously. My problem is the path of negative examples. This is my solution. I put the file "neg.txt" the same path as "opencv_traincascade.exe". And  all the examples are placed in a folder named "neg". And in the "neg.txt" file, I indicate the relative path, looks like this. 
Hope can help people who have the same problem.

```
neg/image1.png
neg/image2.png
neg/image3.png
...
```